# CSV import to mysql for update

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am having a problem when I uploading a CSV file to MySQL. I want to update the data that is present. Here is some example CSV content:

```
John,20,1977
Mary,22,1989
```

In my MySQL database I have:

```
John|18|1977
Mary|22|1990
```

When I upload the CSV file to my MySQL database I want to update the data instead of adding new data. I use PHPMyAdmin to upload the CSV file.

Answer (score 5):

Directly you can't update.

First you need to import data in a temp table. Then compare main table data with temp table data and update using `update` `join`  query.

Step 1) Create another table to use for the import

```
CREATE TABLE temp_table_import LIKE name_maintable;
```

Step 2) Perform the import into temp_table_import

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'somefile.csv' INTO TABLE temp_table_import ...
```

Step 3) Perform an UPDATE JOIN

```
UPDATE name_maintable A
INNER JOIN temp_table_import B USING (id)
SET A.columnname= B.columnname;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can you REPLACE keyword with LOAD DATA for more detail click  [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE name_maintable B
INNER JOIN temp_table_import A USING (id)
SET A.columnname= B.columnname;
```

The last line should read

```
SET B.columnname= A.columnname;
```

as you want to update table B not table A